# How do I connect to the server installed on the host machine from a VMware guest machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-workstation

How do I connect to the server installed on the host (physical) machine from a VMware guest (virtual) machine?

Things like typing "localhost" in the address bar of a browser in a guest machine don't work. My host machine's OS is Windows 7 64 bit, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat the VM like a separate machine.  "localhost" always references the machine it is run on, so if you run it on the guest, it will refer to itself.

You didn't mention what you are trying to connect to, but in general, using the IP address of the host should work (make sure it's the IP that's on the same network segment as the guest VM).